# Por que cuando hago la siguiente consulta me salen columnas repetidas?

Tags: mysql-workbench

uso este select , quiero obtener de las filas (mensaje_id,mensaje,fecha_mensaje,usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario,nom_usuario,usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1,el nombre de usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1 ) con sus repectivos datos,el problema es que me salen columnas repetidas
muchas gracias de antemano

```
SELECT 
l.MENSAJE_id,
l.MENSAJE,
l.FECHA_MENSAJE ,
l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario,
l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1,
r.nom_usuario,
s.nom_usuario
FROM mensaje l
INNER JOIN USUARIO_has_usuario p ON p.usuario_ID_USUARIO = l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario
INNER JOIN USUARIO r ON r.ID_USUARIO = p.usuario_ID_USUARIO
INNER JOIN USUARIO_has_usuario q ON q.usuario_ID_USUARIO1 = l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1 
INNER JOIN USUARIO s ON s.ID_USUARIO = q.usuario_ID_USUARIO1 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// este todoo el script //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;

SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mensagero
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mensagero` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mensagero` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mensagero`.`usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mensagero`.`usuario` (
`id_usuario` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nom_usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`ape_usuario` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`fecha_nac_usuario` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email_usuario` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
`password_usuario` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`celular_usuario` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`fecha_creacion_usuario` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`fecha_modificacion_usuario` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`fecha_eliminacion_usuario` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 22
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mensagero`.`usuario_has_usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mensagero`.`usuario_has_usuario` (
`usuario_id_usuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`usuario_id_usuario1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`usuario_id_usuario`, `usuario_id_usuario1`),
INDEX `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario2_idx` (`usuario_id_usuario1` ASC),
INDEX `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario1_idx` (`usuario_id_usuario` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario1`
FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id_usuario`)
REFERENCES `mensagero`.`usuario` (`id_usuario`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario2`
FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id_usuario1`)
REFERENCES `mensagero`.`usuario` (`id_usuario`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mensagero`.`mensaje`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mensagero`.`mensaje` (
`mensaje_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`mensaje` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
`fecha_mensaje` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`mensaje_id`),
INDEX `fk_mensaje_usuario_has_usuario1_idx` (`usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario` ASC, `usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_mensaje_usuario_has_usuario1`
FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario` , `usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1`)
REFERENCES `mensagero`.`usuario_has_usuario` (`usuario_id_usuario` , `usuario_id_usuario1`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mensagero`.`publicacion`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mensagero`.`publicacion` (
`id_publicacion` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`mensaje_publicacion` VARCHAR(20000) NOT NULL,
`fecha_publicacion` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`usuario_id_usuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_publicacion`),
INDEX `fk_publicacion_usuario1_idx` (`usuario_id_usuario` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_publicacion_usuario1`
FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_id_usuario`)
REFERENCES `mensagero`.`usuario` (`id_usuario`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 3
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

use mensagero;
insert into usuario values ('1','jesus','Huancas','','jhonjesuhuancas@gmail.com','123','960321093',now(),now(),now());
insert into usuario values ('2','jhon','Cordova','','jhoncordova@gmail.com','123456','960321093',now(),now(),now());
insert into usuario values ('3','ana','Vazques','','ana@gmail.com','321','960321094',now(),now(),now());
insert into usuario_has_usuario values ('1','2');
insert into usuario_has_usuario values ('1','3');
insert into mensaje values ('1','Hola que tal como estas',now(),'1','2')
insert into mensaje values ('2','Hola estas bien',now(),'1','3')

SELECT 
l.MENSAJE_id,
l.MENSAJE,
l.FECHA_MENSAJE ,
l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario,
l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1,
r.nom_usuario,
s.nom_usuario
FROM mensaje l
INNER JOIN USUARIO_has_usuario p ON p.usuario_ID_USUARIO = l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario
INNER JOIN USUARIO r ON r.ID_USUARIO = p.usuario_ID_USUARIO
INNER JOIN USUARIO_has_usuario q ON q.usuario_ID_USUARIO1 = l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1 
INNER JOIN USUARIO s ON s.ID_USUARIO = q.usuario_ID_USUARIO1
```

Comment: no necesitas los dos ultimos inner joins

Comment: puedes usar un `DISTINCT` para que no te devuelva las lineas repetidas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba seleccionando valores Distinct así no te traerá campos repetidos si a eso te refieres 
`SELECT DISTINCT
l.MENSAJE_id,
l.MENSAJE,
l.FECHA_MENSAJE ,
l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario,
l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1,
r.nom_usuario,
s.nom_usuario
FROM mensaje l
INNER JOIN USUARIO_has_usuario p ON p.usuario_ID_USUARIO = l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario
INNER JOIN USUARIO r ON r.ID_USUARIO = p.usuario_ID_USUARIO
INNER JOIN USUARIO_has_usuario q ON q.usuario_ID_USUARIO1 = l.usuario_has_usuario_usuario_id_usuario1 
INNER JOIN USUARIO s ON s.ID_USUARIO = q.usuario_ID_USUARIO1`